# tomandjerryhostel.com won't scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I'm having a problem in Google Chrome that isn't happening in any other web browser.

Here is the website: [tomandjerryhostel.com](http://tomandjerryhostel.com)

Google Chrome won't scroll, no matter what I do. I've tried looking online for fixes but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: FYI--I have noticed this issue as a user at timed for certain sites.  For me, it was always a Chrome plugin causing the problem.  Try disabling all of your plugins and then hit the site again to see if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have

```
media="all"
  html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

in your `http://tomandjerryhostel.com/public/style.css`

And body is set to `position:relative` just remove `height: 100%;` from your style.css and then you'll have scrolls :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a position: relative in your body tag:

```
<body id="page1" style="position: relative; min-height: 100%; top: 0px;">
```

I can't see why you'd need that, remove it and you'll be fine.

Comment: @PerfectDark - It works for me in Chrome's Developer Tools. I've switched off the position:relative and I can scroll around

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `overflow` set to `hidden` on `.wrapper`. I'm assuming this wasn't intended, but that's what's causing the scrollbar to be hidden.

Using Chrome's inspect element and finding `.wrapper` you can disable that style attribute and  behavior becomes normal, thus finding your problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i see but when i have remove it my footer line is up.. how to fix next?

Answer (score -5):

Try adding this on your body tag scroll="yes"

```
  <body id="page1"  onLoad="" scroll="yes">
```

Comment: This is completely invalid in everything other than old-IE. It should not be used in any circumstance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534393(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This should not even be necessary. It was a CSS issue anyways.